# Stripe email receipts to customers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'd like Stripe to automatically email receipts to my customers when a successful payment has been made.

I have a WooCommerce store.

The code below is provided by Stripe:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys  

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
'amount' => 999,
'currency' => 'usd',
'source' => 'tok_visa',
'receipt_email' => 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
]);
```

Where do I need to place this code?

Comment: If you are using woocommerce and stripe plugin you can configure the settings to email the receipt otherwise you need to place the code to fire after the purchase form is submitted.

Comment: This is the Stripe information https://stripe.com/docs/receipts Stripe are saying this code needs to be added to enabled automatic receipts.

Comment: So Stripe and Woocommerce have said this function isn't available as default. I need to use the filter, "wc_stripe_send_stripe_receipt", and have it return ‘true’. In terms of being very new to this do I drop the code into my function.php file? What do I need to do regarding 'have it return 'true''?

Comment: @Rich72 Late answer, but it means you add `add_filter( 'wc_stripe_send_stripe_receipt', '__return_true' );` somewhere in your theme or plugin (like functions.php, yes)
I struggle myself with that and it seems Stripe is not sending receipt after that for the test payments, even if enabled in stripe dashboard